# Как заставить ререндериться страницу react native

Tags: reactjs

Есть страница, на которой я пишу To Do List

```
export default function func() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    {id: 1, task: "First", completed: true},
    {id: 2, task: "Second", completed: false}
  ])  
  useEffect(()=>{
    saveTodo(todos);
  },[todos]);
```

Сам же список тудушек задан следующим фрагментом:

```
const ListItem = ({todo}) => {
return <View style={styles.listenItem}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Text style = {{
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 15,
      color: '#1f145c',
      textDecorationLine: todo.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none',
    }}>
      {todo.task}
    </Text>
  </View>

  {!todo?.completed && (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.actionIcon]} onPress={()=>setStatus(todo.id)}>
      <Icon name="check" size={20} color={'#fff'}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
  <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.actionIcon, {backgroundColor: 'red'}]} onPress={() => deleteTodo(todo?.id)}>
    <Icon name="trash-o" size={20} color={'#fff'}/>
  </TouchableOpacity>


</View>}
```

И внутри return

```
<FlatList
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    contentContainerStyle={{padding: 20, paddingBottom: 100}}
    data={todos}
    renderItem={ ({item}) => <ListItem todo={item} />}
/>
```

Я хочу, чтобы при вызове функции setStatus менялась отрисовка элементов списка, что и происходит, когда вызывается другая функция, при которой ререндерится весь компонент, но сама функция setStatus почему-то этого не делает.

```
const setStatus = (todoId) =>{
  var newTodo = todos;
  newTodo.forEach(element => {
    if(element.id == todoId) {element.completed = true; console.log("success")}
  });
  setTodos(newTodo);}
```

Как я понял, useState не видит изменения параметра completed, может есть какой-нибудь другой способ запустить ререндер?

Comment: Так у вас `setStatus` ничего не делает с данными и передает ту же ссылку на массив, что и была до этого, а раз изменений нет, то и менять нечего

Comment: Да, я понял, что при присваивании var newTodo = todos переменной newTodo передается ссылка на todos, а не значения, из-за чего useState не видит изменений :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как я понял, useState не видит изменения параметра completed, может есть какой-нибудь другой способ запустить ререндер?

Просто поменять "где-то" значение ключа не достаточно для вызова рендера... Нужно получить новую ссылку на массив и новую ссылку на измененный объект.

Пробуй сделать вот так

```
const setStatus = (todoId) => {
  var newTodo = todos.map(element => {
    if (element.id == todoId) {
      console.log("success")
      element = {...element, completed: true}
    }
    return element
  });
  setTodos(newTodo);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Теперь пойду читать справочники, чтобы понять почему :)

Comment: @НикитаУльянов, рендер у компонента вызывают изменение стейта и изменение пропсов. Но все эти изменения Реакт должен "распознать". В моем примере изменился весь массив (это уже рендер списка) и один из объектов того массива - это уже рендер компонента который "построен" на данных этого объекта.